# 'Filtering' a modulated signal

Tags: rf

[image: Figure 6-3, Quan, p. 73]

The pictured circuit comes from *Build Your Own Transistor Radios: A Hobbyist's Guide to High-Performance and Low-Powered Radio Circuits* (2012) by Ronald Quan, p. 73.

I am puzzled by Quan’s explanation about a part of this circuit.

L1_Primary and L1_Secondary are coils wound on a ferrite core and used as the receiving antenna for AM broadcasts.

He says on p. 73, “C1 provides an alternating-current (AC) short circuit at high frequencies (e.g., RF frequencies) but a low-pass filtering effect at audio frequencies.”

If I understand this correctly, Quan is saying that the RF portion of the signal is being shorted to ground while the audio frequency signal is being passed onto the connection to L1_Secondary.

The incoming signal at the left hand connection of C1 is a modulated signal.  For the sake of simplicity if I assume that the carrier (519.1 kHz, the tank circuit resonant frequency) is modulated by a 1 kHz tone, then the AM signal at C1 consists of sidebands at 518.1 and 520.1 kHz along with the carrier signal.  That is, there is no low frequency audio to pass along since no demodulating process has yet happened.  It seems to me that C1 kills the very signal which the circuit is trying to process.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the fact that the two coils of L1 are coupled magnetically. The primary is part of the resonant tank circuit, and the RF signal is coupled to the base of the transistor by the secondary, where it is superimposed on whatever audio and bias voltages that are coming through R4.

Comment: Dave,

Thanks for taking the time.

OK, so the RF intentionally gets to the base of Q1 via the magnetic coupling of L1_Primary and L1_Secondary.  So then the purpose of C1 is **not** to filter the RF out of the modulated signal current coming out of L1_Primary, i.e., C1 has no role at the beginning of signal reception, but to filter out any RF that may be in the signal being fed back via R4.

Is that correct?

Comment: No, not quite. C1 can't tell where RF comes from, it acts as an effective short circuit regardless. In terms of the RF, you can think of L1_primary, VC1_RF and VC1_Osc as being completely isolated from the rest of the circuit. Their lower ends ARE grounded by C1. The only coupling to/from them is magnetic. At low frequencies (audio and DC), they have the same voltage on them that the base of Q1 has, but it doesn't affect their operation.